# How to use delegates properly in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I read a lot about the delegates but in practice I cannot use it properly.

Description: I have `A: UIViewController`, `B: UIView`, `C: UIViewController`. I want to run segue from `A: UIViewController` to the `C: UIViewController` from the inside of `B: UIView`.

I've tried:

```
protocol SegueDelegate {
    func runSegue(identifier: String)
}

class B: UIView { ... }
```

where in my `A: UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    B().delegate = self
}

func runSegue(identifier: String) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: self)
}
```

and trying to call it via:

```
@IBAction func send(sender: AnyObject) {
    let a: SegueDelegate? = nil
    a!.runSegue("goToMainPage")
}
```

but I'm sure that I do not use it properly. Can anyone help me with it? I do not want just an answer. Please describe me it concept shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are just a Design Pattern that you can use in a number of ways. You can look at the Apple Frameworks to see how and where to use delegates as examples. A table view delegate is probably the best known delegate in UIKit.

Delegates serve as a callback mechanism for code to communicate with an instance of an unknown class without knowing more than that that instance will respond to the methods of the delegate protocol.

An alternative to a delegate is to use a closure (what we used to call a block in Objective-C). When to use one vs. the other is a matter of taste. There are a couple of rules of thumb, like for instance [outlined here](http://blog.stablekernel.com/blocks-or-delegates/).

What you are doing is, IMO, the proper way to use delegates. You separate the view functionality from the View Controller's functionalities via a delegate, and so the contract for your view is clear: the user needs to respond to the delegate method.

Your code works and is correct. I made a quick implementation here: https://github.com/kristofvanlandschoot/DelegateUsage/tree/master

The main difference from your example, and maybe that's the place where you made a mistake is the third part of your code where you should write something like:

```
@IBAction func send(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.runSegue("segueAB")
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the example! I just want to ask about this line: `self.viewWithDelegate.delegate = self`. I cannot set the view as a delegate `self.view.delegate`. Need I do something additional for this or I understand wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question completely. The ViewControllerA needs to set the  viewWithDelegate's delegate. How else would the viewWithDelegate know how to get the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code, for example:

Here you are creating a new B, and setting A as a delegate of that new instance, no the one you actually want

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    «B()».delegate = self
}
```

And here you are creating force unwrapping a nil value

```
@IBAction func send(sender: AnyObject) {
    let a: SegueDelegate? = «nil»
    «a!».runSegue("goToMainPage")
}
```

---

If what you want to do is tell A to perform a segue to C, from inside B, all you need to do is to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` on A

For example:

```
class B: UIView {
    weak var referenceToA: UIViewController? = nil // set this somewhere
    @IBAction func send(sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let a = referenceToA else {
            fatalError("you didn't set the reference to a view controller of class A")
        }
        a.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToMainPage", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: need I change `weak var referenceToA: UIViewController? = nil` to my own ViewController class or I need to save `UIViewController`?

Comment: with your code I get the next error `fatal error: you didn't set the reference to a variable:` on line `fatalError("you didn't set the reference to a variable")`

Comment: It doesn't matter, your own class is a child of UIViewController and the method you want to use is common to all UIViewControllers, so it will work without changing it. But if you change it, that's ok too

Comment: Of course you get that error, I put it there because I need you to set that variable somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I copied your code. It seems I did not understand it properly

Comment: I did not get this part, especially 'set this somewhere' :/